# Column 'first_name' cannot be null in smarty

Tags: php, mysql, smarty

When i'm inserting form values in to database  it's getting Column 'first_name' cannot be null.
But In DB first_name is not null.but it is displaying null error.

public function save()

{

```
    $sql = "INSERT INTO testimonials SET";
    $sql .= " `first_name` = :first_name ";
    $sql .= ", `last_name` = :last_name ";
    $sql .= ", `job_position` = :job_position ";
    $sql .= ", `company_name` = :company_name ";
    $sql .= ", `date_of_testimonials` = :date_of_testimonials";
    $sql .= ", `testimonials_text` = :testimonials_text ";
    $sql .= ", `fileupload` = :fileupload";
    $sql .= ", `video_link` = :video_link ";
            $sql .= ", `publish` = :publish ";
            $sql .= ", `comments` = :comments ";
    try {

        $stmt = $GLOBALS ["objPDO"]->prepare ( $sql );
        $stmt->bindParam ( ':first_name', $this->first_name, PDO::PARAM_STR );
        $stmt->bindParam ( ':last_name', $this->last_name, PDO::PARAM_STR );
        $stmt->bindParam ( ':job_position', $this->job_position, PDO::PARAM_STR );
                    $stmt->bindParam ( ':company_name', $this->company_name, PDO::PARAM_STR );
        $stmt->bindParam ( ':date_of_testimonials', date ( "Y-m-d H:i:s" ), PDO::PARAM_STR );
        $stmt->bindParam ( ':testimonials_text', $this->testimonials_text, PDO::PARAM_STR );
        $stmt->bindParam ( ':fileupload', $this->fileupload, PDO::PARAM_STR );
        $stmt->bindParam ( ':video_link', $this->video_link, PDO::PARAM_STR );
        $stmt->bindParam ( ':publish', $this->publish, PDO::PARAM_INT );
        $stmt->bindParam ( ':comments', $this->comments, PDO::PARAM_STR );


        if (! $stmt->execute ()) {
            $errorInfo = $stmt->errorInfo ();
            throw new PDOException ( "SQL Error " . $sql . " : " . $errorInfo [2] );
        } else {
        return  $stmt;
        }
        //return new self ( $GLOBALS ["objPDO"]->lastInsertId () );
    } catch ( PDOException $e ) {
        die ( $e->getMessage () );
    }
}
```

Comment: More information would be useful. Show us your database schema, your SQL query, etc.

Comment: So sorry for delay replay,

Comment: CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `testimonials`(
  `testimonials_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `first_name` varchar(250) NOT NULL,
  `last_name` varchar(250) NOT NULL,
  `job_position` varchar(250) NOT NULL,
  `company_name` varchar(250) NOT NULL,
  `date_of_testimonials` varchar(250) NOT NULL,
  `testimonials_text` varchar(250) NOT NULL,
  `fileupload` varchar(250) NOT NULL,
  `video_link` varchar(250) NOT NULL,
  `publish` int(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `comments` text CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`testimonials_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=5 ;

Comment: In above is the table and below is the my query

Comment: public function save()
                {
  $sql = "INSERT INTO testimonials SET";
  $sql .= " `first_name` = :first_name ";
  $sql .= ", `last_name` = :last_name ";
  $sql .= ", `job_position` = :job_position ";
  $sql .= ", `company_name` = :company_name ";
  $sql .= ", `date_of_testimonials` = :date_of_testimonials";
  $sql .= ", `testimonials_text` = :testimonials_text ";  $sql .= ", `fileupload` = :fileupload";
  $sql .= ", `video_link` = :video_link ";
                $sql .= ", `publish` = :publish ";
                $sql .= ", `comments` = :comments ";

Comment: try {
   
   $stmt = $GLOBALS ["objPDO"]->prepare ( $sql );
   $stmt->bindParam ( ':first_name', $this->first_name, PDO::PARAM_STR );
   $stmt->bindParam ( ':last_name', $this->last_name, PDO::PARAM_STR );
   $stmt->bindParam ( ':job_position', $this->job_position, PDO::PARAM_STR );
                        $stmt->bindParam ( ':company_name', $this->company_name, PDO::PARAM_STR );
   $stmt->bindParam ( ':date_of_testimonials', date ( "Y-m-d H:i:s" ), PDO::PARAM_STR );
   $stmt->bindParam ( ':testimonials_text', $this->testimonials_text, PDO::PARAM_STR );

Comment: Add all this in your original question with proper formatting (use the "code sample" option) so it is easily readable please.

Comment: I sent proper formatting.please check it once

Comment: You should try Yasmeen proposition to check if your first_name variable is correct before database insertion.

Comment: yes it is correct Gagaro

Comment: Are you sure the error is raised here ? Can you give us the full error ?

Comment: this is full error  :  SQL Error INSERT INTO testimonials SET `first_name` = :first_name , `last_name` = :last_name , `job_position` = :job_position , `company_name` = :company_name , `date_of_testimonials` = :date_of_testimonials, `testimonials_text` = :testimonials_text , `fileupload` = :fileupload, `video_link` = :video_link , `publish` = :publish , `comments` = :comments : Column 'first_name' cannot be null

Comment: Don't hesitate to add every significant information to your original post. I am not an expert at php development so I can't really help you. Maybe you could print the sql query (with the values) and try to execute it directly on your database to see if it works.

Answer (score 0):

You probably inserting a null value and your field in DB is not nullable. 
What do you mean by "in DB first_name is not null"? Is it empty, is there a data?

Comment: first_name in db is not null.when i inserting form its getting this error.Could you please tell me where is issue

Comment: Print your posted variable and see its value before inserting into DB. If it is null or empty then make sure that you use the right input name in your HTML file. Tell us what you get.